# How to change the default Office365 account?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-account

I'm using Windows 10 Pro 20H2, and my Windows is linked to my "Microsoft Account" (I will name MyPersonalAccount@hotmail.com). **I don't have Office365 subscription on this account**.

Now I have an account from my company (I will name MyCompanyAccount@MyCompany.com), and in **I have Office365 subscription on this account**.

But every time I open any Office app (Word, Excel, etc.), it opens by default in MyPersonalAccount@hotmail.com. Because I use Office365 only for work subjects, I want only it opens using my MyCompanyAccount@MyCompany.com by default. Or else, all times I open some Office app, I need change the account in title top right option.

Comment: Can't you change your Office account in *File > Account > Switch account > Sign in With a different account*?

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I can, but it does not change the default. At least after computer restarts for example, I keep seeing my personal account as default, and I need change to company account again...

Comment: Try in *Control Panel > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials*, under "Generic Credentials" to find and delete all Office credentials, reboot and sign in using your preferred account.

Comment: You may also try to sign out your personal account from Office apps, then go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity`, accoring to the **EmailAddress** value to delete the corresponding key under "Identity" key.